WordPress User Login not accepted although listed in DB
I got a very strange issue with a WordPress Site:
The users are listed in the WP Users Table, the passwords are correct (changed the passcode several times in the DB directly) but WP Login tells me that the Password for every user is wrong.
I changed WP Config to Debug Log True but there is no Log generated whatsoever. I further checked WP Options for the correct Site URL and I did replace all WP Core Files - no effect.
Anyone any idea/hint?
I changed WP Config to Debug Log True but there is no Log generated whatsoever. I further checked WP Options for the correct Site URL and I did replace all WP Core Files - no effect.
I created a dummy html page - strangely not accessible, get 404 not found.
Permission to public_html are set to 770.

You might need to contact your hosting company's support team. The fact that you can't load a dummy HTML page makes me wonder if you're looking at two different sites, somehow.

This is a non managed VPS. But I agree, I just checked DNS and 50% of the DNS Servers return me the correct IP and other 50% do return me a different, unknown IP. But my VPS and my local machine do have the correct IP when asking via nslookup.

Did you change the passwords correctly? Did the passwords contain special characters (can cause issues when changing passwords directly via the database).
If possible, try resetting the passwords with WP-CLI (wp user reset-password). You can also test passwords with WP-CLI (wp user check-password).
